# Fix Top Row while using moveRowAt method

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Good day!

I'm trying to implement the rearrangement of rows by using moveRowAt method.
My task is to fix the top row and make it not editable. I managed to make it not editable by using canEditRowAt method. But I still can change its position by putting other rows in its place. 
How can I completely fix the top cell for any type of rearrangement?

Thank you in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the instance method **tableView(_:targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAt:toProposedIndexPath:)** in UITableViewDelegate and implement as per your need. You can check out the api reference [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614953-tableview).

Sample code would be like as follows.

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, toProposedIndexPath proposedDestinationIndexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath {

        if proposedDestinationIndexPath.row == 0 {
            return IndexPath(row: 1, section: proposedDestinationIndexPath.section)
        } else {
            return proposedDestinationIndexPath
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps. Cheers.!

Comment: It helped! Thank you very much!

Comment: If you find the answer helpful, you can accept and upvote the answer so that it would help others too. Cheers.!